# Всегда ли слова на ультра- пишутся слитно?

Tags: лексика, словообразование, морфемика, слитно-дефис, приставка

В словарях указано, что слова на ультра- пишутся слитно: ультрафиолет, ультраувлажнение, ультразащита.

А в случае с ультра-настройками это правило работает? Ведь здесь, грубо говоря, «ультра» выступает как уточнение, так как настройки могут быть средними и низкими. А в этом случае приставка «ультра» — лишь слово-уточнение, как зомби-босс, ракета-носитель и т. д. Или же всё-таки нужно писать слитно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант ***ультранастройка*** точно не подойдет. Слитное  написание говорит об образовании слова с каким-то новым качеством, например: ультразвук – это звук определенной частоты.

В приведенном примере это скорее приложение (определение), качественная оценка. Формант ***экстра*** в таких случаях пишется через дефис.

**ЭКСТРА-; ЭКСТРА..**. [от лат. extra – вне, снаружи и extra – вне, сверх]
Первая часть сложных слов. Обозначает выход за пределы чего-л.; высшего качества. *Экстра-класс, экстра-матч, экстра-мода, экстра-ревизор.*

Другое дело, что такие слова, как ***ультра-настройка***, не зафиксированы словарем, поэтому его придется считать **авторским неологизмом**.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Скорее всего, ***ультрафарфор*** – это фарфор особого состава, а если написать ***ультра-фарфор***, то получится обычный фарфор, но очень хорошего качества. Но при этом надо помнить, что такие написания пока еще не зафиксированы в словаре.

Comment: Общее название ультрафарфоров — *высокочастотная керамика* и *ультра* в этом слове говорит не о составе, а о изоляционных свойствах (применяется вплоть до СВЧ). Для сравнения, *радиофарфор* предназначен для изготовления деталей радиоаппаратуры.

Comment: Но если она высокочастотная, то это особый вид керамики, наверное, и состав у нее особый. Это как бы новый термин, я это имела в виду. А при дефисном написании производитель просто хвалит свою продукцию, подчеркивает ее качество. Тогда нужно контекст спрашивать у автора вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Словари позволяют образовывать новые слова с приставкой **ультра**. Предложенное Вами слово тоже имеет право на существование, но писаться оно должно по общим правилам — слитно. И указывает оно именно на запредельные значения каких-то количественных характеристик (точно так же как *ультразвук*). В Вашем случае это, вероятно, настройки, позволяющие добиться высокого качества изображения, звука и т.п. В качестве хорошего примера подобного словообразования могу привести широко распространённое в профессиональном узусе, но отсутствущее в общих словарях слово **ультрафарфор**.